# A question on the Substitution for predicate letters theorem as in Kleene Introduction to Metamathematics (1952)

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, foundations, meta-math

I'm self studying Kleene's IM (1952). On page 149 Kleene defines a *name form* thus:

"Let $x_1, ... x_n$ be distinct variables, and $A(x_1, ... x_n)$ a formula. When we are interpreting $A(x_1, ... x_n)$ by a predicate, or performing formal operations with it which are in keeping with an interpretation by a predicate (even though the interpretation is not involved in the formal operations), we call $A(x_1, ... x_n)$ a *name form* in $x_1, ... x_n$ as the *name form variables* ..."

My first question here is which are the formal operations which are in keeping with an interpretation by a predicate and which are not in keeping with an interpretation by a predicate? If, as he says, the interpretation is not involved in the formal operations, why should there even be formal operations in or out of keeping with with the interpretation?

On page 157/8 is goes on with the following definitions in preparation for the SUBSTITUTION FOR PREDICATE LETTERS Theorem (Theorem 15 on page 159):

"By an *occurrence* of a predicate letter $P(a_1, ... a_n)$ with attached variables in a predicate letter formula $E$ we shall mean a (consecutive) part of E of the form $P(t_1, ... t_n)$ where $t_1, ... t_n$ are terms. A predicate letter formula $E$ is said to be a predicate letter formula *in* the distinct predicate letters

(1) $P_1(a_1, ... a_{n_1})$, ..., $P_m(a_1, ... a_{n_m})$, where   $n_1, ... n_m \geq 0; m \geq 1$

if no predicate letter other than (1) occur in $E$.

The substitution of formulas

(2) $A_1(a_1, ... a_{n_1})$, ..., $A_m(a_1, ... a_{n_m})$

considered as name forms in the respective variables shown, for the predicate letters (1) in $E$ (with result $E^*$) shall consist in replacing, simultaneously for each $j(j=1, ..., m)$, each occurrence $P_j(t_1, ... a_{t_j})$ of $P_j(a_1, ... a_{n_j})$ in $E$ by $A_j(t_1, ... t_{n_j})$."

My question here is, why the expressions in (2) have to be name forms and not just formulas?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: IMO it is only a "nitpicking" issue: a *formula* is a specific expression of of the object language. Example page 146: $\exists c (a=0'' \cdot c)$; interpreting it as an arithmetical formula, the formula means (represents) the (unary) predicate (a property): "$a$ is Even".

Comment: In the same way $A(x_1,\ldots, x_n)$ is a formula that expresses a predicate A(x_1,..., x_n) (the difference is typographical).

Answer (score 1):

See Stephen Cole Kleene, [Mathematical logic (1967, Dover reprint)](https://books.google.it/books?id=q-YEuuZ_j8EC&pg=PA77), page 77:

The issue is about the proper way to use symbols to represent a *predicate*.

> The predicate (also called propositional function) named by "$x < y$" can also be named simply "$<$".

The issue is similar to that concerning e.g. the $\sin$ function, that usually we write as $\sin(x)$.

> A notation for predicate using variables we may call a *name form* for the predicate.

See page 78: the "official" syntax is made of *ions* $P(-,-)$ for e.g. binary predicates (with two argument-places) and (individual) *variables*: $x_1,x_2,x_3$.

Thus, an *atom* (or *prime formula*) $P(x_1,x_2)$ is a ion "applied" to variable.

IMO, with a *name form* $P(x,y)$ Kleene means a "generic" name for the ion $P(-,-)$, understanding that it is different from the *atom*.

See page 78:

> We call $P(x,y,z), P(y,z,x)$, etc. different *name forms* for the same 3-place prime predicate expression or ion $P(-,-,-)$.

And see page 98 for the Substitution theorem:

> Say $E$ is a formula which contains only the distinct ions having the respective name forms

> $$\text {(1)  } P_1(w_1,\ldots,w_{P_1}), \ldots P_N(w_1,\ldots,w_{P_1})$$

> [...] The *substitution* of formulas

> $$\text {(2)  } A_1(w_1,\ldots,w_{P_1}), \ldots A_N(w_1,\ldots,w_{P_1})$$

> for (1) in $E$ with *result* $E^*$ [...]